# There is no log when using Rack::FiberPool in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, eventmachine

I'm using [Rack FiberPool](https://github.com/mperham/rack-fiber_pool) with Rails. When I run in development mode there is no log show on the console (neither static assets nor active record log).

The log contains useful information for debugging, how can I get it back to the console?